# Why there is some translation element in Opengl Modelview matrix even when we perform a simple rotation?

Tags: opengl, matrix

I am doing a simple rotation around x axis in opengl as:

```
 glRotatef(rx,1,0,0);
```

I calculated the translation vector from Modelview matrix before and after this operation. What I found surprising was that even we don't see any translation happening on the screen, but still there is some residue translation in the Modelview matrix. Can anyone explain the reason behind that or is it that I am assuming something wrong here.

PS: For calculating the translation vector I have taken transpose of the inversion of ModelView matrix.

Comment: What are actual values of `rx` and `glGetFloatv(GL_MODELVIEW_MATRIX)` array before and after modification?

Comment: rx=0.2 initially and it is incremented in steps.

Comment: Before applying rotation the Modelview matrix is:  `[-0.070819959044456482 0 -0.99748909473419189 0  
   0 0.99999994039535522 0 0  
   0.99748909473419189 0 -0.070819959044456482 0  
   7.62939453125e-006 0 -1780 1]`   and after rotation it is `[-0.070819959044456482 0 -0.99748909473419189 0
   0.0034818868152797222 0.99999386072158813 -0.00024720779038034379 0
   0.9974830150604248 -0.0034906512591987848 -0.07081952691078186 0
   7.62939e-06 0 -1780 1]` considering matrix stored in row major. Here the last row is same after rotation. But Both give two different translation vectors.

Comment: So there was a translation already present; I see no reason why it shouldn't be affected by rotation (although numbers are really small; should be much more visible with higher `rx`). `glRotate` isn't replacing your matrix with rotation, it multiplies current matrix by rotation matrix.

Comment: But that translation is because of zoom factor in modelview matrix. If I calculate Model matrix out of it initial MV matrix will give me {0, 0, 0} whereas the second one gives some residual translation which keeps increasing as rx increases. I want to know whether my procedure of finding Model matrix is correct or not. As i already mentioned I have taken transpose of the inversion of ModelView matrix and then the last column I have extracted as translation vector.

Comment: Are you trying to decompose resulting matrix back to translate/rotate/scale? It usually requires you to have very specific multiplication order, but if translation is 'first', then it is always last four digits of your float array (`7.62939453125e-006 0 -1780 1`), and I don't see it change much except for slight precision truncation (which may be done by `printf`).

Comment: I think I am doing some wrong calculations while calculating Model matrix out from ModelView matrix.